# Why am I not able to Add new Layer to Scene from another Layer by parent?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I don't get why this code is incorrect...

```
    DeadPanelLayer* deadPanelLayer = [DeadPanelLayer node];
    [(CCScene*)self.parent addChild:deadPanelLayer z:2];
```

DeadPanel is a layer that I want to add on the Scene running from another layer

any idea why my layer is not loaded?

**Edit**: the game is not crashing, but the new layer does't show up. I tried to even move the objects on the scene and layer just to make sure it is not displaying due zindex hierarchic

but still...

I tried to add a method on Scene to add the layer in case it is called from parent:

```
[(GameScene*)self.parent showDeadPanel];
```

and even get current scene from Director

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene]
```

and it doesn't work either

Comment: addChild will crash if you are adding a nil child (Check your constructor for DeadPanelLayer) , or if the child already has a parent (check the node method).

Comment: the child is not nil, the new chield doesnt have parent

Comment: What's happening exactly? Is your app crashing, or is the layer just not displaying?

Comment: sorry, updated. It is not crashing

Comment: Does it work if you add the layer directly from the scene, rather than from the child (e.g. in the `init` method)?

Comment: yes it works just fine from the scene creation

Comment: show the init/onenter code in deadpanel, unless z order is the issue the problem s more likely to be found in what and how you add nodes to that layer

Comment: yes the problem was I was adding on the init when the Layer was not yet created, I added a new method and it is working fine. I bought your book a while ago, by the way.